# String manipulation - get part after a certain word

Tags: bash, string, fail2ban

Background: Although I think Fail2Ban is great way of securing subsystems like Apache, it takes a lot of work to get all the info together. So I'm writing a BASH script to do that for me.

I need to put the '**get**' options of **fail2ban-client** in an array ..

So far I isolated these using: `f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act')"`

On the commandline, it looks like:

```
get <JAIL> logpath                       gets the list of the monitored
get <JAIL> logencoding                   gets the encoding of the log files
get <JAIL> journalmatch                  gets the journal filter match for
get <JAIL> ignoreself                    gets the current value of the
get <JAIL> ignoreip                      gets the list of ignored IP
get <JAIL> ignorecommand                 gets ignorecommand of <JAIL>
get <JAIL> failregex                     gets the list of regular
get <JAIL> ignoreregex                   gets the list of regular
get <JAIL> findtime                      gets the time for which the filter
get <JAIL> bantime                       gets the time a host is banned for
get <JAIL> datepattern                   gets the patern used to match
get <JAIL> usedns                        gets the usedns setting for <JAIL>
get <JAIL> maxretry                      gets the number of failures
get <JAIL> maxlines                      gets the number of lines to buffer
get <JAIL> actions                       gets a list of actions for <JAIL>
```

However, the variable looks like:

> get `<JAIL>` logpath gets the list of the monitored get `<JAIL>` logencoding gets the encoding of the log files get `<JAIL>` journalmatch gets the journal filter match for get `<JAIL>` ignoreself gets the current value of the get `<JAIL>` ignoreip gets the list of ignored IP get `<JAIL>` ignorecommand gets ignorecommand of `<JAIL>` get `<JAIL>` failregex gets the list of regular get `<JAIL>` ignoreregex gets the list of regular get `<JAIL>` findtime gets the time for which the filter get `<JAIL>` bantime gets the time a host is banned for get  datepattern gets the patern .. etc.etc.

But I need to have something like:

```
f2b_opts=(logpath logencoding journalmatch ignoreself ignoreip ignorecommand failregex ignoreregex findtime bantime datepattern usedns maxretry maxlines actions)
```

How do I get the word after the `<JAIL>` part?

After days of searching this forum and other sites, still haven't found a solution to this problem. Complicating factors here are the "less" and "greater than" signs and the fact that there are multiple "JAIL" words in the raw string (see example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command to translate the text given (I do not know if it's the input text file or the the result of `f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act')"`, but that doesn't really matter). In both cases you can use this `sed` and `tr` command combination:

```
sed -e "s/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/" input.txt | tr '\n' ' '
```

to get the following output:

> logpath logencoding journalmatch ignoreself ignoreip ignorecommand failregex ignoreregex findtime bantime datepattern usedns maxretry maxlines actions

To function as a part of your command in a pipeline, remove the 'input.txt' part.

If I guess correctly, this may be what you want:

```
f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act' | sed -e "s/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/" input.txt | tr '\n' ' ')"
```

But that's just a guess.

Comment: In your example above you used `()` brackets instead of `{}` brackets. May this cause your troubles?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't see the whole line. But a copy paste of your code left me with an empty string

Comment: OMG, it works (when leaving the **input.txt" part out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh spoke to soon .. when I execute the code on the commandline, it works perfectly, but when executed in a script, it has several "action" words ?? I thought I filtered that out using the `grep -vw `'act'`

Comment: Sorry, but with the given information that is impossible to reproduce for me. It's probably another question. Try to create a new Minimal, Verifiable Example in another question.