# SED failing, why?

Tags: sed, bash-scripting

Also see: [String manipulation - get part after a certain word](https://superuser.com/questions/1529739/string-manipulation-get-part-after-a-certain-word)

My script:

```
    # get list of curent possible F2B 'get' options, as a array (omitting the 'action..') ..
    f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act')"
    f2b_opts="$(sed -e "s/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/" $f2b_opts_cmd | tr '\n' ' ')"
    echo $f2b_opts`
```

What am I doing wrong? This code only gives me a whole list of "sed: can't read .." lines ??

BTW, if I use a pipe construction : `f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act' | sed -e "s/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/" | tr '\n' ' ')"`  it includes "Action" lines I thought were filtered out ?? (When executed on the cmdline, it doesn't include those "Action" lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Just read your previous Q. where an array variable is mentioned. To have `f2b_opts_cmd` as a string variable & `f2b_opts` as a bash array:

```
f2b_opts_cmd=$(fail2ban-client -h | awk '/get <JAIL>/ && !/<ACT>/')
f2b_opts=( $(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$f2b_opts_cmd") )
echo "${f2b_opts[@]}"
```

---

Why the following doesn't work:

```
# get list of curent possible F2B 'get' options, as a array (omitting the 'action..')
f2b_opts_cmd="$(sudo fail2ban-client --help | grep -i 'get <jail>' | grep -vw 'act')"

f2b_opts="$(sed -e "s/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/" $f2b_opts_cmd | tr '\n' ' ')"
:                                                   ^
echo $f2b_opts
```

- The parameter expansion `$f2b_opts_cmd` is providing list of files for `sed` to read from. Instead, direct the result of the parameter expansion to the standard input of `sed`:

```
f2b_opts=$(sed -e 's/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' <<EOF
$f2b_opts_cmd
EOF
)
```

`bash` provides a neater alternative to the above `<<` *here-doc* redirection, known as a *here-string*:

```
f2b_opts=$(sed -e 's/get\s<JAIL>\s\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' <<<"$f2b_opts_cmd")
```

- `grep -vw 'act'` didn't work because the lines you want to filter out are upper case (`<ACT>`). Use `-i` to ignore case, or specify the pattern with appropriate case `grep -vw 'ACT'`

  - As for why it worked when tried on the command line – I can only guess that you might have `grep` aliased to `grep -i`
- No need for `sudo` to see `--help` output
- Using single quotes for arguments is often easier than double quotes – within doubles, certain characters retain a special meaning ( `$` `` ` `` `\` ) – within single quotes only a literal `'` has to be dealt with
- The pipe to `tr` was unnecessary. When `bash` expands an un-quoted substitution, it splits the result into separate words according to the value of the shell variable `IFS` (see the manual for details)
- A pipeline of `... | grep | grep | sed` can usually be replaced by a single `sed` or `awk` script. Working backwards from the original `sed` script provided:

```
f2b_opts=$(fail2ban-client -h | \
    sed -nE '/get <JAIL>/{/<ACT>/!s/(\s*\S*){3}.*/\1/p;}')
```

`awk` seems easier to use for this:

```
f2b_opts=$(fail2ban-client -h | awk '/get <JAIL>/ && !/<ACT>/{print $3}')
```

Comment: Okay, sed and awk just became my next project to study, not quite sure what is going on in the syntax but I can kinda follow what you're doing. BTW, you're right about grep being aliased. Thank you for helping me understand BASH a bit more !